# jQuery hiding and showing multiple element using Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here I have a Button. Same class but multiple buttons per page.

```
<button id="btnIpoDetail" style="margin-top: 10px" class="ui button ipodetailbtn"">
<i class="icon newspaper"></i>
Details
</button>

<button id="btnIpoDetail" style="margin-top: 10px" class="ui button ipodetailbtn"">
<i class="icon newspaper"></i>
Details
</button>
```

Here is the table I want to toggle. Show/Hide

```
        <table class="ui unstackable table ipotablec" id="ipoTable" >
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SO #</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price (MVR)</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1234</td>
            <td>12-02-2012</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td>1,234,534/-</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
```

And here is My Script that I use to hide and show the table using the above button.

```
$(".ipotablec").hide();


$(".ipodetailbtn").click(function(){

    $(".ipotablec").fadeToggle('slow');

});
```

The Problem that I am facing is that,
It works as long as there is one table. But once there are multiple table with same class name, Clicking one buttons toggles all the tables.
How can I fix this?

Comment: Is the order number of the tables you want to hide known in advance? And does your html follow a structure like `<button>` then `<table>` then another `<button>`?

Comment: No. The number of tables are not known in advance. I have a Div grid which has the <button> in it while the table is in the below grid. Both the table and button are in one large div too.

Comment: So its more like
<div id="container">
    <div id="subcontainer>
      <button>Detail</button>
    </div>
   <table>TABLE HERE</table>
</div>

Comment: Do the tables and buttons match in order? Button #1 for table #1 and button #2 for table #2... etc etc...?

Comment: nop. just button 1, and table 1 for all. Even if there are multiple. the below answer works but i need to know how to do it in a loop. Count the number of tables

Answer (score 0):

Replace class with ID, name each table with unique ID names like `table0`, `table1`, etc. That way, you can do `$("#table0").fadeToggle("slow")` or `$("#table1").fadeToggle("slow")`.

Comment: I plan to generate more tables depending on the database. So there are no fixed amount of tables. So in this case I am forced to use classes

Comment: If that is the case, you can do this, `$("table").eq(0).fadeToggle("slow")`. `.eq(0)` means that you are accessing the first table. Similarly, you can do `$("table").eq(1).fadeToggle("slow")` to toggle the second table and so on.

Comment: Is there any way to count the number of tables and us that. Like a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Give each button a unique id:

```
<button id="btnIpoDetail_1" style="margin-top: 10px" class="ui button ipodetailbtn">
    <i class="icon newspaper"></i>
    Details
</button>
```

Give each table a unique id:

```
<table class="ui unstackable table ipotablec" id="ipoTable_1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SO #</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Qty</th>
            <th>Price (MVR)</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1234</td>
            <td>12-02-2012</td>
            <td>350</td>
            <td>1,234,534/-</td>
            <td>Active</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Change your script to something like this (which uses the ids rather than classes). Class selectors will select all elements with that class, id selectors select on the element with that id:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Hide all tables with class = "ipotablec"
    $.each($("table.ipotablec"), function () {

        $(this).hide();

    });

    // Click button with id = "btnIpoDetail_1"
    $("#btnIpoDetail_1").on('click', function () {

        // Table with id = "ipoTable_1"
        $("#ipoTable_1").fadeToggle('slow');

    });

    // Click button with id = "btnIpoDetail_2"
    $("#btnIpoDetail_2").on('click', function () {

        // Table with id = "ipoTable_2"
        $("#ipoTable_2").fadeToggle('slow');

    });

});
```